# Retrieve ArrayList from RESTful service to Jersey client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I have 2 project folders. One for a restful service and one for the client.
Basically my client will call the service and get all notes from a DB of a specific user. (These notes will then be displayed in a table).

This is the error i'm getting (for now):

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
    SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<inventory.Note>.
```

and this

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<Model.Note>, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found.
```

In my restful service i have the following code, that should return an arraylist with all notes based on the username:

```
 @Path("/getAll")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Response login(@FormParam("username") String uname) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    .
    .
    List<Note> note_AL = new ArrayList<Note>();
    .
    .
    (Insert stuf into the array list)
    .
    .
    GenericEntity<List<Note>> generic_list_of_notes = new GenericEntity<List<Note>>(note_AL){};

    return Response.ok(generic_list_of_notes).build();
}
```

Then in my client project, I have a servlet that call the code above:

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Form form = new Form();
    form.add("username", "mike");

    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webR = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/MyNote/api/notes/getAll");

    ClientResponse resp = webR.accept("text/html").post(ClientResponse.class, form);

    //This get printed out (so maybe I have an extra error?
    if (resp.getStatus() != 200){
             System.err.println("Unable to connect to the RESTFUL web service");
    }

    //I get the error here
    ArrayList<Model.Note> output = (ArrayList<Model.Note>) resp.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Model.Note>>(){});

    //Don't know if this is correct. Haven't reached this step because of the above error:
    request.setAttribute("note-all", resp.getEntity(ArrayList.class));
}
```

I have also a Note objects (Note class) in both projects:

```
public class Note {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String color;
    private String date;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
    SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<inventory.Note>.
```

What I did was inserting this on the RESTful code(public Response login)

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

and then changing to the following line, in my clients servlet:

```
ClientResponse resp = webR.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML/*"text/html"*/).post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```